# Installation 20.04.1 - desktop-amd64.iso “Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed” Error

Tags: usb, 20.04, initramfs

USB installation using rufus to create bootable USB. Momentary message “Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed”. This PC has a brand new 1 TB harddrive installed, no operating system.
The last harddrive on PC died lost everything. Get to the following message on the "input/output error during read on /dev/sda", popup in the set location screen. Can get the "Try Ubuntu" up and running. The harddrive can bee seen using sudo lshw -c disk command. Can initramfs be fixed with no os on PC. New to linux and ubuntu.

Comment: Did you check the hash on the downloaded .iso file?

Comment: The "**Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed**" message had been displayed every time when I used my live USB media too, but it worked okay in "Try Ubuntu" mode and it installed Ubuntu all right. Furthermore, the same message appears regularly in the logs of the successfully installed OS. (A google search shows that many people encounter it.)  I would risk, this message might not neccessarily be the reason your installation failed.

Comment: Probably the BIOS offers a function to do a full hardware check. I would run that... Maybe the connector to the disk is at fault? Maybe the motherboard has some physical defect? If yes, it has a chance to ruin your next disk too :(